# IntelliJ Maven Project - Cannot resolve servlet in web.xml

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I've been looking at this problem for hours and haven't been able to see what went wrong.

[image: Here's what it looks like]
My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.pages.crm</groupId>
<artifactId>pagescrm</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- Making sure we get consistent versions -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--Java compiler plugin  1.6, 1.7 or 1.8?-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--Tomcat7 plugin  -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Can anyone please help and identify why I keep getting a `cannot resolve servlet mvc-dispatcher` error?

Comment: If you run maven build from command line does it build or not?

Comment: If definitely doesn't build. Strange thing is I imported the project into Eclipse and everything worked!